# Type 'DateTimeTimeZone' is not assignable to type 'Date' in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, microsoft-graph-api, overloading

I have a problem after updating my entire Angular project where suddenly I get "**No overload matches this call.**" and the error reading "**Type 'DateTimeTimeZone' is not assignable to type 'Date'.**"

This seems to happen to my Date formatting functions:

```
  formattingDate(dateTime: DateTimeTimeZone): String {
    try {
      return (this.datepipe.transform(dateTime, 'dd MMMM yyyy'));
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.alertsService.add('DateTimeTimeZone conversion error', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }
```

While DateTimeTimeZone contains this:

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0
export class DateTimeTimeZone {
  dateTime: string;
  timeZone: string;
}
```

Is there a quick and easy solution to this?
I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Which API are you trying to use?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0](It's in the comments...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using moment and a better format type:

Now:

```
try {
  return moment(dateTime.dateTime).format('MM/dd/yyyy');
}
```

Before:

```
try {
  return (this.datepipe.transform(dateTime, "dd-MMMM-yyyy"));
}
```